# Power current Electicity

Tags: electricity

When A 500 W electric bulb and 500 W heater operates at their rated voltages,the filament of the bulb reaches a higher temperature than the filament of the heater.The most important reason for this is that there dimensions are very different. Why? Can you please explain.

Comment: Do you understand what causes heating?

Answer (score 1):

It might help you answer the question if you have some idea about the dimensions of a heater and of a light filament?

Common types of electrical heaters have a helical coil of resistance wire wound on an insulated former as in the top diagram.
The diameter of the helix might be about 1 cm and its coiled length about 30 cm.

The light bulb has what is called a coil-coil filament made of tungsten whose resistivity is much less than that of the resistance wire.
The length of the coiled  coil-coil might be abound 4 cm.

[image]

If the supply voltage is the same and the power dissipation is the same then the resistance of the heater must be the same as that of the light bulb.

Each of the devices have to dissipated 500 W of light and heat via conduction and/or convection and/or radiation.